# Slack Oauth , multiple domains

Tags: oauth-2.0, slack-api

I have multiple domains hosted for my web application for different clients , i want to add multiple redirect_url's in my slack app , but adding it manually by going in the slack app , so i wanted to know is there any way to add a redirect_uri for my app in my directory using API's instead of manually going and adding it ?

Requirement : Add redirect_URL to my app directory from API instead of going and adding it manually

I tried for adding multiple redirect_URI